# How to get URL of Pipeline Build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

From within a run of Azure Pipeline build, is there any way to get the URL of the build that is running?

Something like:

`https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_build/results?buildId={build_number}`

I would have assumed that it would have been available as one of the environment variables, but it doesn't seem to be.

Comment: Did you tried below solution? How did it go?

Answer (score 17):

This one will work using all predefined variables

```
$buildUrl="$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_build/results?buildId=$(Build.BuildId)" 

Write-Host $buildUrl
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no pre-defined variable of the build URL, but you can get it easily because you have a variable for the build id:

```
steps:
- powershell: |
   $buildUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_build/results?buildId=$(Build.BuildId)"
   Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildUrl;]$buildUrl"
  displayName: 'Set build url variable'
```

In the next step I print the `$(buildUrl)` variable:

[image]

Comment: Use `_build` instead of `_builds`.

Answer (score 5):

Here is alternative using `System.CollectionUri` variable which name is more generic, not specific to TFS. There is no equivalent with project name, so `System.TeamProject` has to be used, which will also work for GitHub repository.

The composed URL can be cached in Azure Pipelines variable in pipeline or job scope:

```
variables:
  MyResultsUrl: '$(System.CollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_build/results?buildId=$(Build.BuildId)'
```

Adding query parameter `?view=logs` you can make the URL jump straights to the logs.

Comment: This worked fine for me.
Use $(System.CollectionUri) instead of $(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)